# If $\text{ }\big(x-\frac{1}x\big)=i\sqrt{2}$. Then compute $\bigg(x^{2187}-\frac{1}{x^{2187}}\bigg)$. Here $i=\sqrt{-1}$

Tags: complex-numbers, solution-verification, quadratics

> **QUESTION:** If $\text{ }\big(x-\frac{1}x\big)=i\sqrt{2}$ , $\text{ }$then compute $$\bigg(x^{2187}-\frac{1}{x^{2187}}\bigg)$$ Here $i=\sqrt{-1}$ .

---

**MY ANSWER:** I have done it using the Quadratic formula and De Moivre's Theorem. Let me write down my working before I propose my doubt.. Here's how I did it..

Solving the equation we get $$x^2-(i\sqrt{2})x-1=0$$ $$\implies x=\frac{i\sqrt{2} \pm \sqrt{(i\sqrt{2})^2+4}}{2} $$ $$\implies x=\frac{i\sqrt{2}\pm\sqrt{2}}{2}$$ Take $x=(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}i)=e^{\frac{i\pi}4}$

Now we know that $2187=(273\times8)+3$

$$\therefore x^{2187}=e^{2187\times \frac{i\pi}4}=e^{(273\times 2\pi + \frac{3\pi}4)i}=e^{\frac{{3\pi}}{4}i}=\frac{i-1}{\sqrt{2}}$$

$$\therefore x^{2187}-\frac{1}{x^{2187}}= \frac{i-1}{\sqrt{2}}-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{i-1}$$ $$=\frac{(i-1)^2-2}{(i-1)\sqrt{2}}$$ $$=\frac{2}{\sqrt{2}}\frac{(1+i)}{(1-i)}$$ $$=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} (1+i)^2$$ **$$=\boxed{\sqrt{2}i}$$**

> > Now my first question is that, the quadratic relation gave us **two different** values for $x$. One with which I have worked out to reach the answer of $\sqrt {2}i$ and the other, $\big(-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}i\big)$ which I had left behind. Now working with that I find that the angle turns out to be $\frac{\pi}{10}$ and stuff becomes much more complicated after that. The official answer to this one is $\sqrt{2}i$ (which matches with what I have found out).

> > **My doubt is why do we not consider the other value of $x$ ?**

> > *And is there any alternative (preferably simpler) method(s) to solve this one?*

Thank You so much for your help and support.. **:)**

Comment: The other value of $x$ does actually come out the same, but to solve the question via your method, you *do* need to verify this fact.

Comment: It might be mentioned that the quadratic polynomial you developed is one factor of $$ (x^2-(i\sqrt2)x-1) \ · \ (x^2+(i\sqrt2)x-1) \ \ = \ \ x^4 + 1 \ \ = \ \ 0 . $$  So  your values for $ \ x \ $ are two of the four fourth-roots of $ \ -1 \ \ , $ a fact which "powers"   the arguments in  the answers posted.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

$2187=3^7$. This is a clue. Powers of $3$ are significant. Now
$$\left(x-\frac1x\right)^3=(i\sqrt2)^3=-2i\sqrt2$$
and
$$\left(x-\frac1x\right)^3=x^3-\frac1{x^3}-3\left(x-\frac1x\right)
=x^3-\frac1{x^3}-3i\sqrt2.$$
So
$$x^3-\frac1{x^3}=i\sqrt2.$$
Repeating this,
$$x^9-\frac1{x^9}=i\sqrt2,$$
$$x^{27}-\frac1{x^{27}}=i\sqrt2$$
etc.
Eventually,
$$x^{2187}-\frac1{x^{2187}}=i\sqrt2.$$

Comment: Smart attack!! Hats off.. Thank you so much for clearing my doubt.. :D

Comment: But can you say that when I follow the quadratic method, why don't I get $i\sqrt{2}$ for the second root of $x$, which I have left off in my solution..

Comment: For the "quadratic method" you get $x=\exp(\pi i/4)$ or $x=\exp(3\pi i/4)$ not $x=i\sqrt2$.

Answer (score 1):

In fact, it is easy to verify that both values of $x$ yield the same result. For the whole problem, you just need De Moivre's formula twice (two lines of paper without explanation).

For $x=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}i$, you have shown the answer is $i\sqrt 2$.

Now, let $x=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}i=\cos \frac{3\pi}{4} + i\sin \frac{3\pi}{4}$. Using the De Moivre's formula and the fact that
$$z-\frac{1}{z}=2i\sin(\arg(z))$$
you get
$$x^{2187}-\frac{1}{x^{2187}} = x^3-\frac{1}{x^3} = 2i\sin\frac{9\pi}{4}=i\sqrt 2$$ Done!

Comment: That was my question.. How do I solve for the other value? According to the official answer, they have just given it to be $\sqrt{2}i$ , which is similar to what I have found out.. But I also have to verify that the other value yields the same result..

Comment: @StrangerForever That was quite simple. See the edit.

Answer (score 0):

Your result from the quadratic formula can also be handled in this fashion.  Since
$$ \ z \  = \  \frac{i\sqrt{2}\pm\sqrt{2}}{2} \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ z_1 \ = \ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}  ·  (1 + i) \ \ = \ \ e^{\pi / 4} \ \ , \ \ z_2 \ = \ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}  ·  (-1 + i) \ \ = \ \ e^{3\pi / 4} \ \ , $$
we have $ \  \frac{1}{z_{1}} \ = \ e^{-\pi / 4} \ = \ \overline{z_1} \ \  $ and, similarly, $ \  \frac{1}{z_{2}} \  = \ \overline{z_2} \ \ . $  We then confirm that $$ z_{1,2} \ - \ \frac{1}{z_{1,2}}  \ \ = \ \ z_{1,2} \ - \ \overline{z_{1,2}} \ \ = \ \ 2  ·  \mathfrak{Im}(z_{1,2}) \ \ = \ \ 2  ·  \left(\frac{i}{\sqrt2} \right) \ \ = \ \ i·\sqrt2 \ \ . $$

We note the following properties:

• $ \ \ -z_1 \ = \ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}  ·  (-1 - i) \ \ = \ \ e^{-3\pi / 4} \ = \ \overline{z_2} \ \ $ and $ \ -z_2 \ = \ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}  ·  (1 - i) \ \ = \ \ e^{-\pi / 4} \ = \ \overline{z_1} \ \ ; $

• $ \ \ \ z_1^4  \ = \ e^{4 \ · \ (\pi / 4)} \ = \ -1 \ = \ z_2^4  \ = \ e^{4 \ · \ (3\pi / 4)} \  \ \Rightarrow \  \ z_{1,2}^8 \ = \ 1 \ \ . $

From the foregoing, we obtain $$   z_{1,2}^3  \ =   \ -\frac{1}{z_{1,2}} \ \ = \ \  -\overline{z_{1,2}} \ \  . $$

We may then calculate that
$$  z^{2187} \ - \ \frac{1}{z^{2187}} \ \ = \ \ z^{(8·273) \  + \ 3} \ - \ \frac{1}{z^{(8·273) \  + \ 3}} \ \ = \ \ (z^8)^{273}   ·  z^3  \ - \ \frac{1}{(z^8)^{273}   ·  z^3}    $$
$$ = \ \  1  · z^3_{1,2}  \ - \ \left(\frac{1}{1· z_{1,2}} \right)^3  \ \ = \ \ z^3_{1,2}  \ - \ (\overline{z_{1,2}})^3 \ \ = \ \ -\overline{z_{1,2}}  \ - \ \left( \ -\overline{\overline{z_{1,2}}} \ \right) \ \ = \ \  z_{2,1}   \ - \  \overline{z_{2,1}}   \ \ ,  $$
which we have seen earlier is equal to $ \ i·\sqrt2 \ \ . $

$$ \ \ $$

**ADDENDUM (12/14) --**

Another approach makes use of the factorization of a "difference of odd powers": we may write
$$  z^{2187} \ - \ z^{-2187} $$
$$ = \ \ (z \ - \ z^{-1}) \ · \ (z^{2186} \ + \ z^{2185} · z^{-1} \ + \  z^{2184} · z^{-2} \ + \ \ldots \ + \ z^{2} · z^{-2184} \ + \ z^{1} · z^{-2185} \ + \ z^{-2186}) $$
$$ = \ \ (z \ - \ z^{-1}) \ · \ (z^{2186} \ + \ z^{2184}  \ + \  z^{2182}   \ + \ \ldots \ + \ z^2 \ + \ z^0 \ + \ z^{-2} \ + \ \ldots \ + \    z^{-2182} \ + \ z^{-2184} \ + \ z^{-2186}) \ \ . $$

From the results you derived, we obtain
$$ z_1^2 \  =  \ e^{\pi / 2} \  = \  i \ \ \ , \ \ \ z_2^2  \ =  \ e^{3\pi / 2} \  = \  -i \ \ , $$

from which it follows that
$$ z_1^2 \ + \ z_1^4 \ + \ z_1^6 \ + \ z_1^8 \ \  =  \ \    i \ + \ (-1) \ + \ (-i) \ + \ 1 \ \ = \ \ 0 \ \ ,  $$
$$ z_2^2 \ + \ z_2^4 \ + \ z_2^6 \ + \ z_2^8 \ \  =  \ \    (-i) \ + \ (-1) \ + \ i \ + \ 1 \ \ = \ \ 0 \ \ ,  $$
and, since $ \  \frac{1}{z_{1,2}} \  = \ \overline{z_{1,2}} \ \ , $ we also have
$$ z_{1,2}^{-2} \ + \ z_{1,2}^{-4} \ + \ z_{1,2}^{-6} \ + \ z_{1,2}^{-8} \ \  =  \ \   \overline{0} \ \ = \ \ 0 \ \ .  $$

The "central terms" of the summation-factor are
$$ \ldots \ + \ (z^8 \ + \ z^6 \ + \ z^4 \ + \ z^2) \ + \ z^0 \ + \ (z^{-2} \ + \ z^{-4} \ + \ z^{-6} \ + \ z^{-8}) \ + \ \ldots $$
and with $ \ z_{1,2}^8 \ = \ 1 \ \ , $ we can write, for instance,
$$ z^{10} \ + \ z^{12} \ + \ z^{14} \ + \ z^{16} \ \  =  \ \ z^8 \ · \    (z^2 \ + \ z^4 \ + \ z^6 \ + \ z^8) \ \   = \ \ 0   $$
and $$ z^{-10} \ + \ z^{-12} \ + \ z^{-14} \ + \ z^{-16} \ \  =  \ \ z^{-8} \ · \    (z^{-2} \ + \ z^{-4} \ + \ z^{-6} \ + \ z^{-8}) \ \   = \ \ 0 \ \ . $$

Since $ \ 2184 \ = \ 273·8 \ \ , $ our factorization reduces to just
$$  z_{1,2}^{2187} \ - \ z_{1,2}^{-2187} \ \  = \ \ (z_{1,2} \ - \ z_{1,2}^{-1}) \ · \ (z_{1,2}^{2186} \ + \  z_{1,2}^0 \ + \  z_{1,2}^{-2186}) \ \ . $$

It was given that $ z_{1,2}  -  \frac{1}{z_{1,2}}  \   = \  i\sqrt2 \  $  and we have said that $ \  \frac{1}{z_{1,2}} \  = \ \overline{z_{1,2}} \ \ . $  Hence,
$$  z_{1,2}^{2187} \ - \ z_{1,2}^{-2187} \ \  = \ \ (i·\sqrt2) \ · \ (z_{1,2}^{2186} \ + \  1 \ + \  \overline{z_{1,2}^{2186}}) \ \ . $$

Finally, $ \ z_{1,2}^{2186} \ = \ z_{1,2}^{273·8 \ + \ 2} \ = \  z_{1,2}^2 \ \ , $  leading to
$$  z_1^{2187} \ - \ z_1^{-2187} \ \  = \ \ (i·\sqrt2) \ · \ ( \ i \ + \  1 \ + \  \overline{i} \ ) \ \ = \ \ (i·\sqrt2) \ · \ 1 $$
and
$$  z_2^{2187} \ - \ z_2^{-2187} \ \  = \ \ (i·\sqrt2) \ · \ ( \ -i \ + \  1 \ + \  \overline{-i} \ ) \ \ = \ \ (i·\sqrt2) \ · \ 1 \ \ . $$